# Trouble adding matrices together

Tags: haskell, matrix

I'm having trouble compiling the following:

```
data Matrix = Matrix [[Float]] deriving (Eq)

aditionMat :: Matrix -> Matrix -> Matrix
aditionMat m1 m2 = Matrix $ zipWith (zipWith (+)) m1 m2
```

I'm working on defining a custom matrix data type, but the method I made for adding two matrices together won't work.
`aditionMat` works fine when I give it two `[[Float]]`, but won't compile when I feed it two `Matrix`.
The error is the following:

Couldn't match expected type `[[Float]]` with actual type `Matrix`  (for both m1 and m2)

Apologies for the very trivial question but I can't see why it fails

Answer (score 5):

`m1` and `m2` are `Matrix`es, not `[[Float]]`s, so you can not use `zipWith` on these. You need to unwrap the list of lists from the `Matrix` data constructor:

```
aditionMat :: Matrix -> Matrix -> Matrix
aditionMat (Matrix m1) (Matrix m2) = Matrix $ zipWith (zipWith (+)) m1 m2
```

Comment: Thank you as always!